# Changing how certain field are displayed in my views when baked with Cake

Tags: php, cakephp

In `app/Console/MyTheme/view.ctp`, I have this snippet:

```
if ($isKey !== true) {
    echo "\t<dt><?php echo __('" . Inflector::humanize($field) . "'); ?></dt>\n";
    echo "\t<dd><?php echo h(\${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}']); ?>&nbsp;</dd>\n";
}
```

Do I have something at my disposal to determine the type of field being worked on? Essentially, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
if ($isKey !== true) {
    echo "\t<dt><?php echo __('" . Inflector::humanize($field) . "'); ?></dt>\n";
    if($field['type'] == 'Something')
        //do something here
    else
        echo "\t<dd><?php echo h(\${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}']); ?>&nbsp;</dd>\n";
}
```

The goal would detect tinyint(1) and have the display of "Yes" or "No" when baked. Or does this functionality exist already?

**Edit #1**

It just occurred to me that my boolean fields are all prefixed with "is_". I could potentially do something like this:

```
if ($isKey !== true) {
    echo "\t<dt><?php echo __('" . Inflector::humanize($field) . "'); ?></dt>\n";
    if(strpos($field, "is_") !== false)
        echo "\t<dd>Yes or No</dd>\n";
    else
        echo "\t<dd><?php echo h(\${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}']); ?>&nbsp;</dd>\n";
}
```

**Edit #2**

This works to some extent:

```
if ($isKey !== true) {
            echo "\t<dt><?php echo __('" . Inflector::humanize($field) . "'); ?></dt>\n";
            if(strpos($field, "is_") !== false)
                echo "\t<dd><?php echo \${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}'] ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></dd>\n";
            else
                echo "\t<dd><?php echo h(\${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}']); ?>&nbsp;</dd>\n";
    }
```

Comment: You can watch formHelper to understand how can it detect the right input type to use with every field, I guess you have to load the associated model and inspect his schema to find the field type.

Comment: When I’m baked, everything looks pretty different all by itself already …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what I was looking for (as all my boolean fields are prefixed with "is_"):

```
if ($isKey !== true) {
            echo "\t<dt><?php echo __('" . Inflector::humanize($field) . "'); ?></dt>\n";
            if(strpos($field, "is_") !== false)
                echo "\t<dd><?php echo \${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}'] ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></dd>\n";
            else
                echo "\t<dd><?php echo h(\${$singularVar}['{$modelClass}']['{$field}']); ?>&nbsp;</dd>\n";
    }
```